# DOM XSS via JQuery function init()

Tags: web-application, xss, javascript, jquery

Burp reported potential DOM XSS. Data is read from location and passed to the 'init()' function of JQuery via:

```
var table = location['table'] || location['sysparm_table'];
snPresence.init(table, sys_id, query);
```

URL looks as such,

> https://publicsite.com/scripts/Scoreboard/js_includes_cmdb_scoreboard.jsx

**Is this vulnerable? How can I check if vulnerable with Chrome DevTools?**

Portswigger also mentions the init() sink of JQuery as leading to DOM XSS
https://portswigger.net/web-security/cross-site-scripting/dom-based

Comment: Welcome Romanenko!  This is probably a method of a library you are using. I think you should investigate inside that init() method. As I know, there is no default init() method of JQuery, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Pilfility there is [one](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/init.js?ts=2) but it don't know that it is the one referenced in the code snippet and **anecdotally** it is not something that I have seen used in the wild